# Navigationbar not filling under status bar when clicked from side menu?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have a navigation bar created by the nav controller for my view, these are loaded via a container side menu.

When i click an item, it loads the nav controller and view, but the nav bar background drops out showing a blank background colour on the status bar.

Any idea how I can diagnose this issue? I have included some view debugger screenshots to best illustrate

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

```
  UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor().appThemeColour()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: Are you using SideMenu pod ?

Comment: are you removing nav bar shadow somewhere?

Comment: im using interactivesidemenu https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu

Comment: adding my nav config appearance into the OP now

Comment: Is the problem the status bar background color or the navigation bar background color?

Comment: status bars dont have background colours, its 100% the nav bar background being short

Comment: Status bars may not have a backgroundColor property but a status bar of statusBarStyle default does have a black background. But I am glad you know the answers to your questions.

Comment: already checked and issue persists with statusBarStyle as default or light

Answer (score 0):

Well you are missing one thing here and thats setBackgroundImage of UINavigationBar.

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor().appThemeColour()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Comment: unfortunately that had no effect on the issue, i think its more to do with the sidemenu effecting it

Answer (score 0):

*Note this is the solution for Sidemenu Library named "https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu/"

Change status bar end alpha property to 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find code below.

```
@objcMembers
open class SideMenuPresentationStyle: InitializableClass {

/// Background color behind the views and status bar color

open var backgroundColor: UIColor = .white`
```